# When is it safe to delete the local Maven repository?

Tags: maven

In which circumstances is it safe respectively unsafe to `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository` provided that I'm working online and I have access to all needed artifacts via remote repositories.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you retrieve all dependencies from remote repositories, then the local repo becomes nothing more than a cache.

Like all caches, the Maven local repo can occasionally become "dirty". In an acknowledged act of paranoia and overkill, I schedule a periodic cron job to purge the local repositories on my build machines. This forces a re-sync with my Nexus Maven repository.

Comment: Good explanation and thanks for the extra hint about forced re-sync.

Comment: Why not simply use mvn -U (update) to force a check for update?

Comment: @imagineerThat Sure, but a cache reset ensures the build is completely clean. Doesn't cost  much when dependencies are also cached locally in the Maven respository.

Comment: On Linux, I don't really need to purge local repo except for Jenkins builds (building clean). On windows builds time lags when many local snapshots are kept. So windows routine purges are good. The local cache should always be expendable. However, I have run into cases where one light of 300 modules was set to never deploy.

Answer (score 14):

If you have access to all needed artifacts via remote repos, it is always safe to remove local Maven repository. All artifacts needed to the next build, including even basic Maven plugins (like compiler) will be basically fetched from remote repos. That's it.

Answer (score 5):

So instead of doing the "brute force" way, there is a different option:

brute force:

rm -rf ~/.m2/repository

Here is the "mvn" way to do this.

"everything:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

some arguments that I find helpful

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false
```

Here is what I typically do for my ***local*** machine:  (where I use an option parameter of a "groupid", which is a little more controlled than a big-hammer/brute-force.....

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude="my.group.id" -DsnapshotsOnly=true  -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false
```

you can investigate the command line options here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is add a cron entry to regularly delete files in the local repository for a given period, say 90 days.

```
find ~/.m2/ -type f -atime +90 -delete && \
    find ~/.m2/ -type d -empty -delete
```

This keeps your cache size down to only artifacts you've been using recently.